# Binding from a property of each item inside an ItemsControl to a property of an object outside the ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl, and a Button outside the ItemsControl. Each item inside the ItemsControl has a dependency property called "MyProperty" (defined in the code-behind).

I would like to set the IsEnabled property of the Button to false when at least one of the items in the ItemsControl has the MyProperty property set to 5. (of course this is just a stupid example of a more complicated situation)

I tried by means of a data trigger, but with no luck:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="cancellami24.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" Value="5">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="MyButton" Value="False" /><!--error on TargetName-->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="MyListBox" Grid.Row="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Grid.Row="1" Click="MyButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace cancellami24
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<MyItem> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myCollection.Add(new MyItem(1));
            myCollection.Add(new MyItem(2));
            myCollection.Add(new MyItem(3));
            MyListBox.ItemsSource = myCollection;
        }

        private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myCollection[2].SetValue(MyItem.MyPropertyProperty, 5);
        }
    }

    public class MyItem : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MyItem));

        public MyItem(int propertyValue)
        {
            SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, propertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom converter to solve it

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    bool flag = false;
    var collection = value as ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    if(collection==null) return flag;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item.MyProperty==5)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Add MyConverter to your App.xaml

```
<local:MyConverter x:key="MyConverter"/>
```

Xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I want that the IsEnabled property of the button changes whenever I change a MyProperty property in one of the items. I've tested your solution (by fixing it a bit), and unfortunately the IsEnabled property is updated only once at the application start.